# Why does this SQL SELECT only work when a value is specified?

Tags: sql, select

Following SQL statement gives me a correct result when putting a specific load into the where clause [`and a.t$load = '123456789'`].

```
SELECT a.t$type, a.t$load, b.t$wght, k.calc FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b 
    ON a.t$load = b.t$load and a.t$type = b.t$type 

    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT t$load, t$type, SUM(q.calculation) calc FROM 
            (SELECT y.t$type, y.t$load, (y.t$dqua * x.t$wght) calculation FROM table1 y
                LEFT JOIN table3 x
                ON x.t$item = y.t$mitm
            ) q
        group by t$load, t$type) k
    ON k.t$load = a.t$load and k.t$type = a.t$type

where a.t$type = '123'
and a.t$load = '123456789'
group by a.t$type, a.t$load, b.t$wght
```

When I remove this condition, every single calc value is `NULL`. Why is that? How can I connect the sub queries to calculate "calc" correctly by every load?

The tables are linked like this:

- table1: the same load can appear multiple times with different items
- table2: for every load there is a weight (-> relation from t1 to t2 is n:1)
- table3: every item from t1 has a weight in t3 (1:1) which should be multiplied with the quantity and summed by load.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve].)

Comment: I think you are mistaken.  The result set just happens to start with unmatched values but if you scroll enough, you will see matches.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no there aren't any. there are ~ 300k results, all of them are NULL in calc...

Comment: @Kinaeh . . . What condition are you  referring to.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't understand your question. You said, there might be any matched values below the NULL values, but there aren't any values in calc-column at all.

Comment: @jarlh how can I format a sample table on stackoverflow? I tried with tab spaced but it turned out awfully...

Comment: Put an empty row before, and 4 <space> first in each row. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One null value can ruin the result for `SUM` and other SQL aggregation functions.  trying adding an `ISNULL` the sum of `calculation`.  I also added some validation in the nested queries.

```
SELECT 
a.t$type, a.t$load, b.t$wght, k.calc 
FROM 
table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.t$load = b.t$load and a.t$type = b.t$type 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
     t$load, t$type, SUM(ISNULL(q.calculation,0)) calc -- isnull check before we sum.
     FROM 
        (SELECT y.t$type, y.t$load, (y.t$dqua * x.t$wght) calculation FROM table1 y
            LEFT JOIN table3 x
            ON x.t$item = y.t$mitm
            where y.t$dqua is NOT NULL AND x.t$wght is NOT NULL
            -- add these conditions, to eliminate nulls from the result.
        ) q
    group by t$load, t$type) k
ON k.t$load = a.t$load and k.t$type = a.t$type
where 
a.t$type = '123' and a.t$load = '123456789' 
group by 
a.t$type, a.t$load, b.t$wght
```

I hope this helps you down the right path.

Comment: This is totally false.  You should delete the answer.  Aggregation functions ignore `NULL` values.

Comment: This really helps, as I get now values, but there must be another error in my select statement, because now, every single "calc" has the same value. Guess there is something wrong in joining, as I only want to sum the weights of items in the same load per load...

Comment: @Kinaeh what is the error in your statement now? Update the question.  I can assist.

Comment: @GlennFerrie it's not a real error, it's just that the 'calc' column has the same value in every record... i'll try to figure out why and maybe come back later. Thank you very much for your help already!

Comment: OK.  Cool. Take care